# Mongodump have index, collections but no documents

Tags: mongodb

I am just a beginner with MongoDB.

I have created little script to backup and restore my mongodb base (on localhost)

But my dump contains index, collections, but NO documents ?

Here is the script (on Windows 7):

```
cd "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\"
mongodump.exe --db aya --out e:\mongodb
```

i obtain files :
*.bson are empty
*.metadata.bson are filled

And When i restore this dump, I lost all documents.

Someone can help me to understand ? :)

Thanks a lot for everyone with good will :)

Comment: do you have any documents in the source db? Are you using the same version of mongodb as mongo shell?

Comment: Yes same version, but strangely today It works ...